# Can't rewrite wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, rewriting

how rewrite custom file in wordpress? I'm using wordpress as site engine, and I need to rewrite index.php?custom_site=Hello%20world

How rewrite Hello%20world to Hello-world?

For example:

Rewrite this
http://example.com/index.php?custom_site=Hello%20world
TO
http://example.com/index.php?custom_site=Hello-world

I have tried a lot of htaccess rules, but nothing works. Wordpress site ignoring new htaccess rules...

PHP info shows, that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Is the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files enabled at all? If so, then turning on rewrite logging will give you very valuable insight into what is going on inside the rewriting engine when processing a request. Amongst other things you will see the pattern getting applied to the paths alongside the outcome.

Comment: I always stumble when people use the term "to rewrite some url" like that. It is the wrong way 'round. Like people expect that the links sent out somehow magically are rewritten the way they defined in some `.htaccess` style file. So once more, just to make sure we talk about the same thing: a rewrite rule rewrites an _incoming_ request to another internal or external request. It does _not_ somehow modify links you output.

Comment: Apart from that: please show the rule or rules you tried so far so that we can try to help sort them out.

Comment: I reverted your edit because edit a question with the answer is not how SO works, nor putting "SOLVED" in the title is acceptable. It's absolutly fine and encouraged to answer your own question. If you find the answer by yourself, please mark your answer as "accepted" . Please refer to [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)